# MySQL update returns 0 rows affected in transaction

Tags: mysql, transactions, sql-update, rows-affected

Table account have special field 'executor' for daemons to know that account is blocked for update with one of daemons.

Step by step:

1. start transaction
2. block account with:

   ```
   UPDATE `account` SET `executor` = 2727 WHERE `executor` is NULL AND `id` = 1234;
   ```
3. some operations. During this step another daemons can select row with id=1234 and try to update it(or update another fields, not 'executor')
4. account status back with:

   ```
   UPDATE `account` SET `executor` = NULL WHERE `executor` = 2727 AND `id` = 1234;
   ```
5. commit

Some times at step 4 mysql returns success execution status, but 0 rows affected. It happens 1 time at 10000 transactions.

What am I doing wrong? Or its mysql bug?

UPDATE:

after the observations I get the following:

1) first we do

```
UPDATE `account` SET `executor` = 2727 WHERE `executor` is NULL AND `id` = 1234;
```

2) transaction blocks record

3) during transaction I do

```
`UPDATE `account` SET `balance` = 1 WHERE `id` = 1234;`
```

4) after this query

```
SELECT `executor` FROM `account` WHERE `id`=1234
```

gives result 2727

after several repetitions of points 3 and 4 we get result `executor`=NULL... or 0, as I write the result to a variable with type int, but this is likely all the same NULL... but it is not so important.. in any case executor ceased to be a value 2727

further transaction is rolled back...
if again repeat operation, everything is fine without resetting value of executor...

Comment: You have multiple processes running and are seeing a collision between two processes updating the same account ID?

Comment: but after second step record must lock in transaction, isnt it?